# how to fix no output to console window in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement, console-output

When running program I have no output to my console window,

Tried selecting different console windows, closing and reopening the window, closing other open code

```
package Codecademy;

public class Continents {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//This will show a continent and the largest city
    int contient = 4;
    String contientString;

    switch (contient) {
    case 1:
        contientString = "North America: Mexico city Mexico";
        break;
    case 2:
         contientString = "South America: Sao Paulo, Brazil";
break;
case 3:
contientString = "Europe: Moscow, Russia";
break;
case 4:
contientString = "Africa: Lagos, Nigeria";
break;
case 5:
contientString = "Asia: Shanghai, China";
break;
case 6:
contientString = "Australia: Sydney, Australia";
break;
case 7:
contientString = "Antarctica: McMurdo Station, US";
break;
default:
contientString = "Invalid Selection";
break;

}
}
}
```

South America: Sao Paulo, Brazil (Should be the correct output.)

Comment: What code are you talking about?

Comment: something like system.otut.println("the correct case")?

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: @DevilsHnd the assignment is to write a code that selects a case from the the switch statement.

Comment: If you want `South America: Sao Paulo, Brazil` to be the output then **contient** needs to equal 2: `int contient = 2;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then it should be something like this:

```
int contient = 4;
String contientString;

switch (contient) {
    case 1:
        contientString = "North America: Mexico city Mexico";
        break;
    case 2:
        contientString = "Some 2nd Continent: Some 2d City Some2ndCountry";
        break;
    case 3:
        contientString = "Some 3rd Continent: Some 3rd City Some3rdCountry";
        break;
    case 4:
        contientString = "Some 4th Continent: Some 4th City Some4thCountry";
        break;
    default:
        contientString = "Don't Know What Continent: UNKNOWN";
}

System.out.println(contientString);
```